# How does php determine the needed internal type of a variable?

Tags: php, types, casting, internals

This is a question about PHP internals and how it works under the hood:

How does php decide that:

```
$a = 3;
```

needs to be an integer (internally)?

and how that

```
$a = "3";
```

needs to be a string?

I once heard that PHP uses to cast every variable around (to different types) to determine its needed internal data type, but when trying to verify this statement I was not able to find anything about in the Internet.

There are some weird examples on the official PHP doc which describe some of the language's strange behavior:

> source: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

```
<?php
$foo = "0";  // $foo is string (ASCII 48)
$foo += 2;   // $foo is now an integer (2)
$foo = $foo + 1.3;  // $foo is now a float (3.3)
$foo = 5 + "10 Little Piggies"; // $foo is integer (15)
$foo = 5 + "10 Small Pigs";     // $foo is integer (15)
?>
```

but that does not answer my question.

It just shows how dynamic PHP is on a very obscure way.

I don't think that has anything to do with evaluation (for example "":=false but "abc":=true), doesn't it?

One more question: how can php extract a "primitive" integer from a String like "10 Small Pigs"? Could this be done by typecasting (internally) or does this require some kind of string processing with included char converting or something?

Comment: This is a good read about it: https://entwickler.de/webandphp/how-php-manages-variables-125644.html

Answer (score 1):

PHP will automaticall convert values from one type to another as necessary. If the variable contains a string, but you use it in an arithmetic expression, it will convert it to a number. If it contains a number, but you use it as the argument to a function that needs a string, it will convert it to a string.

When you perform comparisons, if the types of the two values are different, one of them will be converted to the other type (unless you use the "strict" comparison operators, `===` and `!==`). The [type comparison tables](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) explain which will be converted depending on the two types.

When you do the initial assignments, like

```
$a = 3;
$b = "3";
$c = false;
```

it looks at the syntax. If the value is in quotes, then it's a string. If the value is a bare number, it's a number. So `$a` contains a number, `$b` contains a string. `$c` contains a boolean because it was assigned from a boolean literal.

If you assign the variable using a function call, it depends on what the function returns (e.g. `substr` returns a string); all the standard PHP functions have their return types specified in the documentation.

Most of the time, what it does in all these cases is what intuitively seems "right" from the syntax and likely semantics.

Comment: this is really a interesting thing to know but it does not answer my question I guess: This does not explain **how** php decides/determines what type a variable needs to be of, when the interpreter runs over a line that tells `$a=3`. Okay PHP auto converts variables, but how does it know the type to convert to? Can this really be done that easy as it sounds when you say "if it contains a string.."? Does php only determine by quotes if a variable needs to be a String on initialization? This is somehow confusing me

Comment: I added some explanation of simple assignments.

Answer (score 0):

For your second question, you can use intval.

From php.net, http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php

> (PHP 4, PHP 5)
>
> intval — Get the integer value of a variable
>
> int intval ( mixed $var [, int $base = 10 ] )
>
> Returns the integer value of var, using the specified base for the
>   conversion (the default is base 10). intval() should not be used on
>   objects, as doing so will emit an E_NOTICE level error and return 1.